# Having an add_action( 'user_new_form',)

Tags: actions, s2member

I am using the following action;

```
add_action( 'user_new_form', 'epx_add_user_form_to_admin_area',489);
function epx_add_user_form_to_admin_area($current){
   $current .= 'this is a test';
   echo $current;
}
```

The issue is the minute i put that in s2member which displays a load of options on the add user page in the admin not to display

[image: screen]

^^That is when i have not got anything that whats s2 member shows

[image: screen]

^^That is when i use the code above.

It is like it is overwritten what s2member wants to display. 
What is the best way to output new themes without removing s2member items which are required!

Many Thanks for any help.

Comment: This might be better aimed at plugin's developers/support. Just looking at your snippet it seems like nothing problematic.

Comment: Are you sure $current is a string?  Do var_dump($current) before you change it.

Comment: I believe the variable passed by this action is a `$user` object, not a string. try this: `function epx_add_user_form_to_admin_area( $user ) { echo "this is a test"; }`

Comment: Sadly that does not work or resolve it. I adding the variable to see if it was something being passed into it. I have contacted the plugin developer and waiting for a reply. Once i have a answer i will post the answer.

Comment: "UP" I have the same issue, Yes, it is a string.