# action user_new_form param is a string

Tags: user-meta, profiles

In the action `user_new_form`, the parameter `$user` returns a string `add-new-user`.

I've used `esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( '_typeuser', $user->ID ) );` but I get an error.

Another [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174386/having-an-add-action-user-new-form) on the topic is non-response at the moment but I've patched the problem with:

```
/* PROFIL FIELD */
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'user_new_form', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields');

function my_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) {

    if(is_string($user) === true){
        $user = new stdClass();//create a new
        $user->ID = -9999;
    }
    $newsletter = esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( '_newsletter', $user->ID ) );
    unset($user);
}
```

How we can fix this problem without creating an object and setup `$user->ID` to `-9999` for new user?

Comment: [The documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_new_form/) says that parameter is called `$type`, not `$user`. Presumably that `get_the_author_meta()` line is in your callback for this hook, so you know the user can't exist? So you can't use any ID?

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139614/wordpress-add-new-user-hooks#answer-23067428. Specially `if(current_filter() == 'user_new_form'`

Answer (score 0):

use like this:

$id = $user->ID;

And if user is new set $id = 9999

```
function my_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) {

    if(is_string($user) === true){
        $user = new stdClass();//create a new
        $id = -9999;
    }
    $newsletter = esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( '_newsletter', $id ) );
    unset($user);
}
```

Comment: That may save him creating a temp user object in that particular code since he's only passing the ID (and I don't think `$user` is a global) but doesn't solve the general problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if ID member is set:

```
function my_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) {
    $id = isset($user->ID)? $user->ID : -9999;
    $newsletter = esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( '_newsletter', $id ) );
}
```